# Issue with installing SOAP on MediaTemple server

Tags: php, soap, installation, woocommerce, mediatemple

I followed the steps to install the SOAP module found here (https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1947/Configure+PHP+with+SOAP) but it didn't seem to work. When I run "php", I get the following error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? I'm trying to enable SOAP for some Woocommerce plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a php version issue. I was trying to install SOAP for the wrong version of php.